llama_index.indices.list.retrievers import error
from llama_index import GPTListIndex
from llama_index.indices.list.retrievers import ListIndexLLMRetriever

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader('./data').load_data()
index = GPTListIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context=service_context)
retriever = ListIndexLLMRetriever()
....

I try to import my python program with 
python 3.8.1 and 3.11.0
pip install llama-index==0.5.6
pip install langchain==0.0.148 
these versions are suggested in this github
https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/4064 
but  all get the error message：
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.indices.list.retrievers'
Does anyone have any suggestions to solve it?

In terms of LLM-frameworks, those versions are ancient. Won't your problems be solved by using recent ones?

pip install llama-index --upgrade Was released 5 Hour ago. The version is llama-index 0.10.59

In llama-index, ListIndexLLMRetriever was added only as part of the release 0.6.13. This requires Langchain version to be 0.0.154.
Therefore, changing the version to the one specified below should solve your problem.
pip install llama_index==0.6.13
pip install langchain==0.0.154

Note: Do verify that other parts of the code are not broken by this change.
